# Where do terminated incomplete downloads go when using firefox?

Tags: firefox

Where do terminated incomplete downloads go when using firefox?

Answer (score 2):

They should stay in the designated folder. Mine is /Downloads, and they can have either the filename.part or some weird name.part. Either way, they should be in your downloads or designated folder. If you cannot find it, right click and do show in finder, and it will open the folder containing it.

Answer (score 0):

To the "great bit-bucket in the sky".  Whenever I cancel a download with Firefox, it cleans up after itself.  Leaving partial downloads around is abnormal, e.g., if I crashed or killed Firefox during the download.

Comment: In fact, if you crashed or killed Firefox, removing partial downloads would be abnormal, because it would neglect the possibility of *resuming* it, which on a large file can be a pain if not available. Now when you explicitly cancel it, then that's another story and it would be removed (or at least it should ask).